# Liquibase changesets to InMemory database (EF)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, liquibase, in-memory-database

I have many liquibase changsets and execute it before integrations test. 
Now I want to use EF InMemory for tests. 
Is it possible to forward liquibase changesets to InMemory database?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. Just create a copy of database connection settings, which will point to your test database, and use them while running tests.

Comment: and please, how will look connectionstring for liquibase?

Comment: @ArkadySpiridonov it's impossible to answer this question without any code that you are currently using. The original question was "Is it possible... ". The answer is "Yes, it is possible", and I've just described the way it's usually done. If you need more specific answer, you should provide some code for others to start from.

Comment: Sorry for imprecise question, but as I think now - liquibase don't see EF inmemory DB. 
Source code - just inmemory EF DB 

            return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>()
                 .UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName)
                 .Options;

And liquibase config is :

driver: ?Idon't know
classpath: ?Idon't know
url: ?Idon't know
changeLogFile: changelog.xml
defaultSchemaName=public

liquibase.bat --defaultsFile=local.properties

So, you see - problems with my connection string.